# Android webview & javaScriptInterface like functionality in Gluon to save javascript response from login webpage in webview

Tags: android, javafx, webview, gluon, gluon-mobile

In android if I want to use an already existing login webpage, I can use webview and javaScriptInterface to save token values from javascript response after login success. Is there a similar functionality to save the token values using the pre-existing login webpage in GluonHQ?

Comment: By 'pre-existing login webpage' you mean using the built in login methods with social network profiles?

Comment: No my website already has coldfusion login page setup

Comment: So what you want is getting access to a WebView using some script? The JavaFX WebView on Android doesn't support it yet.